# Backup a database using JPA (Design)

Tags: jpa, database-backups

I have a working code that doesn't work always. Here's my approach:

**Creating the backup**

1. Create Entity Manager for source database
2. Create Entity Manager for destination database (embedded Derby Database)
3. Copy entities (Select all entries of a table (table order hard coded right now) and copy them to the destination database. Basically a select all and the detach entity from source and persist on destination)
4. Zip the embedded Derby database.

**Loading from backup**

1. Unzip backup
2. Perform a backup
3. Clean destination database (delete all tables)
4. Copy entities

At some point I would use JPA 2 Metadata to fetch the tables to be copied and select the order they need to be copied (due to constraints).

For some reason this approach doesn't work always as I see "lost" entries that are not recovered.

Here's the code:

```
package com.bluecubs.xinco.core.server;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter;
import org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.TrueFileFilter;

/**
 * This is a complex task and is heavily dependant on the architecture
 * of the database.
 * 
 * Data needs to be stored in a particular order into the database to comply 
 * with database constraints. This order can be observed in a dump file or
 * create script like the ones generated from MySQL Workbench. Using that 
 * should be enough. In case that tool is not available basically the logic is
 * populating tables from the outside inwards. From the tables with no relationships
 * or only one working to the more complex ones. As summary before a table is populated all
 * the related tables should be populated already (if we have identifying relationships.
 *
 * @author Javier A. Ortiz Bultrón <javier.ortiz.78@gmail.com>
 */
public class XincoBackupManager {

    private static XincoBackupManager instance;
    private static EntityManagerFactory liveEMF;
    private static EntityManagerFactory backupEMF;
    private static EntityManager live, backup;
    private static final ArrayList<String> tables = new ArrayList<String>();
    private static XincoBackupFile last;
    private static String backupPath;
    public static HashMap<String, Integer> stats = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    static {
        //Non-order-critical tables
        tables.add("XincoCoreAceT");
        tables.add("XincoCoreDataT");
        tables.add("XincoCoreDataTypeAttributeT");
        tables.add("XincoCoreGroupT");
        tables.add("XincoCoreLanguageT");
        tables.add("XincoCoreNodeT");
        tables.add("XincoCoreUserHasXincoCoreGroupT");
        tables.add("XincoCoreUserT");
        tables.add("XincoSettingT");
        tables.add("XincoDependencyTypeT");
        tables.add("XincoCoreDataHasDependencyT");
        tables.add("XincoSetting");
        tables.add("XincoId");
        //Order critical tables
        tables.add("XincoCoreLanguage");
        tables.add("XincoCoreNode");
        tables.add("XincoCoreDataType");
        tables.add("XincoCoreData");
        tables.add("XincoDependencyType");
        tables.add("XincoCoreDataHasDependency");
        tables.add("XincoCoreUser");
        tables.add("XincoCoreUserModifiedRecord");
        tables.add("XincoCoreGroup");
        tables.add("XincoCoreAce");
        tables.add("XincoCoreUserHasXincoCoreGroup");
        tables.add("XincoAddAttribute");
        tables.add("XincoCoreDataTypeAttribute");
        tables.add("XincoCoreLog");
    }

    public static XincoBackupManager get() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new XincoBackupManager();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private static void setDBSystemDir(String systemDir) {
        // Set the db system directory.
        System.setProperty("derby.system.home", systemDir);
        Logger.getLogger(XincoBackupManager.class.getSimpleName()).log(Level.FINEST,
                "Derby home set at: {0}", systemDir);
        try {
            //Start the embeded DB
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver").newInstance();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(XincoBackupManager.class.getSimpleName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(XincoBackupManager.class.getSimpleName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(XincoBackupManager.class.getSimpleName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    private static void initConnections() {
        try {
            liveEMF = XincoDBManager.getEntityManagerFactory();
        } catch (XincoException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(XincoBackupManager.class.getSimpleName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        try {
            backupEMF = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("XincoBackup");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(XincoBackupManager.class.getSimpleName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    protected static boolean backup() throws XincoException {
        try {
            Logger.getLogger(XincoBackupManager.class.getSimpleName()).log(Level.FINEST,
                    "Initializing connections...");
            initConnections();
            stats.clear();
            backupPath = XincoSettingServer.getSetting("setting.backup.path").getString_value();
            //We need to make sure that there's no one in the database
            XincoDBManager.setLocked(true);
            live = liveEMF.createEntityManager();
            //Prepare the backup repository. Create dirs if needed.
            File backupDir = new File(backupPath);
            backupDir.mkdirs();
            //Create folder for this backup
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
            File backupNewDir = new File(backupPath + System.getProperty("file.separator")
                    + format.format(new Date()));
            backupNewDir.mkdirs();
            /*
             * Make sure there's no derby database stuff in the folder.
             * Any previous interrupted backup might left corrupted database files.
             */
            File tempDir = new File(backupNewDir.getAbsolutePath()
                    + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "xinco");
            if (tempDir.exists()) {
                Logger.getLogger(XincoBackupManager.class.getSimpleName()).log(Level.WARNING,
                        "Deleting potentially corrupted database files at: {0}", tempDir);
                FileUtils.deleteDirectory(tempDir);
                //Delete Derby log file
                FileUtils.forceDelete(new File(backupNewDir.getAbsolutePath()
                        + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "derby.log"));
                Logger.getLogger(XincoBackupManager.class.getSimpleName()).log(Level.INFO,
                        "Done!");
            }
            /**
             * Prepare system to use derby
             */
            setDBSystemDir(backupNewDir.getAbsolutePath());
            backup = backupEMF.createEntityManager();
            for (String s : tables) {
                copyEntities(s, live, backup);
            }
            /**
             * At this point we should have a <Backup Database name> folder in
             * <Backup Path>/<Date>.
             * Lets zip them for storage.
             */
            format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM dd yyyy hh-mm-ss");
            zipBackupFiles(backupNewDir, backupNewDir.getAbsolutePath()
                    + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "Xinco Backup " + format.format(new Date()));
            //Stop Derby database in order to delete
            try {
                DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:;shutdown=true");
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                //When the database shuts down it'll throw an exception
            }
            //Delete backed up files
            String dbName = (String) backup.getProperties().get("javax.persistence.jdbc.url");
            dbName = dbName.substring(dbName.lastIndexOf(":") + 1, dbName.indexOf(";"));
            Logger.getLogger(XincoBackupManager.class.getSimpleName()).log(Level.FINEST,
                    "Deleting temp folder: {0}", dbName);
            FileUtils.deleteDirectory(new File(backupNewDir.getAbsolutePath()
                    + System.getProperty("file.separator") + dbName));
            //Delete Derby log file
            FileUtils.forceDelete(new File(backupNewDir.getAbsolutePath()
                    + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "derby.log"));
        } catch (XincoException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(XincoBackupManager.class.getSimpleName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            XincoDBManager.setLocked(false);
            return false;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(XincoBackupManager.class.getSimpleName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            XincoDBManager.setLocked(false);
            return false;
        } finally {
            if (live != null && live.isOpen()) {
                live.close();
            }
            if (backup != null && backup.isOpen()) {
                backup.close();
            }
            if (backupEMF != null && backupEMF.isOpen()) {
                backupEMF.close();
            }
        }
        XincoDBManager.setLocked(false);
        return true;
    }

    private static void zipBackupFiles(File path, String zipName) throws XincoException {
        if (!zipName.endsWith(".zip")) {
            zipName += ".zip";
        }
        // These are the files to include in the ZIP file
        IOFileFilter filter = new IOFileFilter() {

            @Override
            public boolean accept(File file) {

                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    return true;
                }
                //Ignore other backup files
                if (file.isFile() && !file.getName().endsWith(".zip")) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean accept(File file, String string) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
            }
        };
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Collection<File> fileList = FileUtils.listFiles(path, filter, TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE);
        Object[] files = fileList.toArray();

        // Create a buffer for reading the files
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];

        try {
            // Create the ZIP file
            ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zipName));

            // Compress the files
            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream((File) files[i]);
                String fileName = ((File) files[i]).getPath();
                //Remove not needed folders
                fileName = fileName.substring(fileName.indexOf(path.getAbsolutePath()) + path.getAbsolutePath().length() + 1);
                // Add ZIP entry to output stream.
                out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(fileName));

                // Transfer bytes from the file to the ZIP file
                int len;
                while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                    out.write(buf, 0, len);
                }

                // Complete the entry
                out.closeEntry();
                in.close();
                last = new XincoBackupFile(new File(zipName));
            }
            // Complete the ZIP file
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new XincoException("Error zipping backup: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }

    private static void copyEntities(String table, EntityManager source, EntityManager dest) {
        List<Object> result, result2;
        result = source.createNamedQuery(table + ".findAll").getResultList();
        Logger.getLogger(XincoBackupManager.class.getSimpleName()).log(Level.INFO,
                "Copying from table: {0}", table);
        int i = 0;
        source.clear();
        for (Object o : result) {
            i++;
            Class<?> persistenceClass = null;
            try {
                persistenceClass = Class.forName("com.bluecubs.xinco.core.server.persistence." + table);
                dest.getTransaction().begin();
                if (dest.contains(persistenceClass.cast(o))) {
                    //If no exception do a merge because it exists already
                    dest.merge(persistenceClass.cast(o));
                } else {
                    dest.persist(persistenceClass.cast(o));
                }
                dest.getTransaction().commit();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(XincoBackupManager.class.getSimpleName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                throw new XincoException("No persistence enitiy defined for table: " + table);
            }catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(XincoBackupManager.class.getSimpleName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                throw new XincoException("Exception copying: " + o);
            }
        }
        stats.put(table, i);
        result2 = dest.createNamedQuery(table + ".findAll").getResultList();
        Logger.getLogger(XincoBackupManager.class.getSimpleName()).log(Level.INFO,
                "Copying for table: {0} completed! Amount of records: {1}",
                new Object[]{table, i});
        //Make sure the copy is accurate.
        //TODO: For some reason XincoId always return twice the amount of records during this routine.
        if (result2.size() != result.size() && !table.equals("XincoId")) {
            throw new XincoException("Error copying records for table " + table + ". Got " + result2.size() + " instead of " + result.size());
        }
        result2.clear();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked"})
    public static ArrayList<XincoBackupFile> getBackupFiles() throws XincoException {
        // These are the files to include in the ZIP file
        IOFileFilter filter = new IOFileFilter() {

            @Override
            public boolean accept(File file) {
                //Only zip files
                if (file.isFile() && file.getName().endsWith(".zip")
                        && file.getName().startsWith("Xinco Backup")) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean accept(File file, String string) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
            }
        };
        Collection<File> files = FileUtils.listFiles(
                new File(backupPath), filter, TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE);
        ArrayList<XincoBackupFile> backupFiles = new ArrayList<XincoBackupFile>();
        for (File f : files) {
            backupFiles.add(new XincoBackupFile(f));
        }
        //Sort
        Collections.sort(backupFiles, new XincoBackupComparator());
        //Sorted from oldest to newer so we need to invert the list.
        Collections.reverse(backupFiles);
        return backupFiles;
    }

    protected static boolean restoreFromBackup(XincoBackupFile backupFile) throws XincoException {
        try {
            stats.clear();
            Logger.getLogger(XincoBackupManager.class.getSimpleName()).log(Level.FINEST,
                    "Restoring database from: {0}", backupFile.getName());
            //First make a backup of current database just in case
            Logger.getLogger(XincoBackupManager.class.getSimpleName()).log(Level.FINEST,
                    "Creating a restore point for your current database...");
            backup();
            //We need to make sure that there's no one in the database
            XincoDBManager.setLocked(true);
            //Load database from the provided backup
            loadDatabaseFromBackup(backupFile);
            XincoDBManager.setLocked(false);
            Logger.getLogger(XincoBackupManager.class.getSimpleName()).log(Level.FINEST,
                    "Restore complete!");
            try {
                Logger.getLogger(XincoBackupManager.class.getSimpleName()).log(Level.FINEST,
                        "Deleting restore point...");
                FileUtils.forceDelete(last);
                Logger.getLogger(XincoBackupManager.class.getSimpleName()).log(Level.FINEST,
                        "Done!");
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(XincoBackupManager.class.getSimpleName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            return true;
        } catch (XincoException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(XincoBackupManager.class.getSimpleName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            //Recover from last backup
            loadDatabaseFromBackup(getLast());
            XincoDBManager.setLocked(false);
            throw new XincoException("Unable to load backup! Database reverted to original state. \n" + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    protected static void loadDatabaseFromBackup(XincoBackupFile backupFile) throws XincoException {
        EntityManager backupEM = null;
        try {
            initConnections();
            live = liveEMF.createEntityManager();
            //Unzip backup
            unzipBackup(backupFile);
            //Delete current database (inverse order than writing)
            Collections.reverse(tables);
            for (String s : tables) {
                clearTable(s, live);
            }
            //Get back to original order
            Collections.reverse(tables);
            //Make derby start where the backup is
            Logger.getLogger(XincoBackupManager.class.getSimpleName()).log(Level.FINEST,
                    "Connecting to backup data...");
            setDBSystemDir(backupPath + "Temp"
                    + System.getProperty("file.separator"));
            //Connect to backup database
            backupEM = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("XincoBackup").createEntityManager();
            //Start copying
            Logger.getLogger(XincoBackupManager.class.getSimpleName()).log(Level.FINEST,
                    "Starting loading entities...");
            for (String s : tables) {
                //Copy values from backup
                copyEntities(s, backupEM, live);
            }
            Logger.getLogger(XincoBackupManager.class.getSimpleName()).log(Level.FINEST,
                    "Load complete!");
            //Stop Derby database in order to delete
            DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:;shutdown=true");
            Logger.getLogger(XincoBackupManager.class.getSimpleName()).log(Level.FINEST,
                    "Delete temp folder!");
            try {
                FileUtils.deleteDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("derby.system.home")));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(XincoBackupManager.class.getSimpleName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            //When the database shuts down it'll throw an exception
        } finally {
            if (live != null && live.isOpen()) {
                live.close();
            }
            if (backupEM != null && backupEM.isOpen()) {
                backupEM.close();
            }
        }
    }

    private static void unzipBackup(XincoBackupFile backup) {
        try {
            //Make sure that the temp directory is empty before unzipping
            FileUtils.deleteDirectory(new File(backupPath
                    + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "Temp"));
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            ZipInputStream zipinputstream = null;
            ZipEntry zipentry;
            zipinputstream = new ZipInputStream(
                    new FileInputStream(backup.getBackupFile()));
            zipentry = zipinputstream.getNextEntry();
            Logger.getLogger(XincoBackupManager.class.getSimpleName()).log(Level.FINEST,
                    "Unzipping backup file: {0}", backup.getName());
            while (zipentry != null) {
                //for each entry to be extracted
                String entryName = zipentry.getName();
                Logger.getLogger(XincoBackupManager.class.getSimpleName()).log(Level.FINEST,
                        "Extracting file: {0}", entryName);
                int n;
                FileOutputStream fileoutputstream;
                File newFile = new File(entryName);
                String directory = newFile.getParent();

                if (directory == null) {
                    if (newFile.isDirectory()) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (entryName.contains(System.getProperty("file.separator"))) {
                    //Create any internal folders required
                    new File(backupPath
                            + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "Temp"
                            + System.getProperty("file.separator") + entryName.substring(
                            0, entryName.lastIndexOf(
                            System.getProperty("file.separator")))).mkdirs();
                } else {
                    File tempDir = new File(backupPath
                            + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "Temp"
                            + System.getProperty("file.separator"));
                    tempDir.mkdirs();
                }
                fileoutputstream = new FileOutputStream(backupPath
                        + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "Temp"
                        + System.getProperty("file.separator") + entryName);

                while ((n = zipinputstream.read(buf, 0, 1024)) > -1) {
                    fileoutputstream.write(buf, 0, n);
                }

                fileoutputstream.close();
                zipinputstream.closeEntry();
                zipentry = zipinputstream.getNextEntry();

            }//while
            zipinputstream.close();
            Logger.getLogger(XincoBackupManager.class.getSimpleName()).log(Level.FINEST,
                    "Unzipping complete!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.getLogger(XincoBackupManager.class.getSimpleName()).log(Level.SEVERE,
                    "Error unzipping file!", e);
        }
    }

    private static void clearTable(String table, EntityManager target) throws XincoException {
        try {
            List<Object> result;
            result = target.createNamedQuery(table + ".findAll").getResultList();
            Logger.getLogger(XincoBackupManager.class.getSimpleName()).log(Level.FINEST,
                    "Cleaning table: {0}", table);
            int i = 0;
            Class<?> serverClass = null;
            boolean special = false;
            try {
                serverClass = Class.forName("com.bluecubs.xinco.core.server." + table + "Server");
                special = serverClass.newInstance() instanceof XincoCRUDSpecialCase;
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                try {
                    //Class doesn't exist, try in the add folder
                    serverClass = Class.forName("com.bluecubs.xinco.add.server." + table + "Server");
                    special = serverClass.newInstance() instanceof XincoCRUDSpecialCase;
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex1) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex1) {
                } catch (NoClassDefFoundError ex1) {
                }
            } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            } catch (NoClassDefFoundError ex) {
            }
            if (serverClass != null && special) {
                ((XincoCRUDSpecialCase) serverClass.newInstance()).clearTable();
                special = false;
            } else {
                for (Object o : result) {
                    i++;
                    try {
                        Class<?> persistenceClass = Class.forName("com.bluecubs.xinco.core.server.persistence." + table);
                        target.getTransaction().begin();
                        target.remove(persistenceClass.cast(o));
                        target.getTransaction().commit();
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(XincoBackupManager.class.getSimpleName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
            }
            result = target.createNamedQuery(table + ".findAll").getResultList();
            if (!result.isEmpty()) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to delete entities: " + result.size());
            }
            stats.put(table, i);
            Logger.getLogger(XincoBackupManager.class.getSimpleName()).log(Level.FINEST,
                    "Cleaning table: {0} completed! Amount of records removed: {1}", new Object[]{table, i});
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(XincoBackupManager.class.getSimpleName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(XincoBackupManager.class.getSimpleName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return the last
     */
    public static XincoBackupFile getLast() {
        return last;
    }
}
```

Any flaw in the design?
A better way of doing it?
Any comment is more than welcomed!

Answer (score 2):

> Any flaw in the design? A better way of doing it? Any comment is more than welcomed!

Most database engines provides commands or tooling allowing to dump the content of a given database (some of them even supporting incremental backups). JPA will just be less efficient, more complex while you have **ready to use** solutions so I don't see the point of using JPA for this task.

For Derby, there is actually nothing to do: just zip/tar (or use rsync) the database files and you're done.

And if you want to copy the content of one database engine to another engine, use an ETL.

#### See also

- [How i can Dump a derby database into an sql file?](http://markmail.org/thread/dkq46wwalzogw2nn)

Comment: I can't access that link. I think is blocked at my work place. Any other option to see it?

Comment: I was looking for a generic way of doing this since the application can be in any database engine supported by JPA. Usually my end users don't have the technical knowledge to do this or are not DBA's

Comment: @javydreamercsw: I've updated the link to point to another archive site. Regarding your second comment, I understand better now. But I think an ETL would be the right tool for the job and I would look in this direction instead of developing my own tool.

Answer (score 1):

An interesting option I've found is [Scriptella](http://scriptella.org/) which can be called from Java code. [Usage examples](http://snippets.dzone.com/tag/scriptella). I'll give it a try and post the results.

Comment: Scriptella sure works but is not as easy as I would like. Datanucleus option is easier.

Answer (score 1):

Always better done *in* the datastore. Some JPA providers provide ways. The one we provide is
http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform/jpa/replication.html

Comment: Looks really interesting but it didn't work in my case. I filled a bug: http://www.datanucleus.org/servlet/jira/browse/NUCJPA-75

For some reason is not working with Eclipselink JPA 2 and Datanucleus claims to support JPA2 as well.

Comment: Why would you ever think that using EclipseLink with a DataNucleus extension would work ? If you want to do replication with EclipseLink then you go to their docs and see what they offer you. Use DataNucleus with DataNucleus extensions

Comment: Based on the API I wasn't attempting anything illegal. See the bug for details.

Any guide on on how to migrate to DataNucleus?